# Return to previous buffer without going through every jumplist entry

Tags: buffers, jumplist

When I've jumped from a buffer to another buffer I use `C-o` to return and after that I use `C-i` if I want to jump to that same buffer again. I think this is the common approach. The problem is that this requires you to step through *every* preceding jumplist entry until you get back to the previous buffer. I'm in the habit of jumping around files with `M-{` and `M-}` so there is usually tons of unimportant clutter in the jumplist.

How can I solve this problem?