# How can I jump to the previous file?

Tags: jumplist

`<c-i>` and `<c-o>` jump to the previous location in the jump list. However, I often open a file, do some searching in it, and then have to press `<c-o>` a lot to get back to the original file. Is there a command that traverses back through the jump list until it gets to a different file, so I can get back with only one keypress?

(yes, I could just set a mark, but I can never remember to do that.)

Comment: How is this different from http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/503/return-to-previous-buffer-without-going-through-every-jumplist-entry ?

Comment: @msb Not different, but the other question doesn't really have the answer I want. I guess I need to write a plugin...